# Running multiple instances of a jar at the same time: memory issue

Tags: linux, scala, jvm

Right now I am running multiple instances of a jar (code written in scala) at the same time on a cluster with 24 cores and 64G memory, with `Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-15-generic x86_64)`. I observe an issue of heavy memory usage, which is super-linear to the number of instances I run. To be more specific, here is what I am doing

1. Code in scala and use sbt to pack into a jar.
2. Login to the cluster, use `screen` to open a new screen session.
3. Open multiple windows in this screen.
4. In each window, run `java -cp myjar.jar main.scala.MyClass`

What I observe is that, say when I only run 7 instances, about 10G memory is used, and everything is fine. Now I run 14 instances. Memory is quickly eaten up and all 64G is occupied, and then the machine slows down dramatically and it is even difficult to log in. By monitoring the machine through `htop`, I can see that only a few cores are running at a time. Can anyone tell me what is happening to my program and how to fix it so that I am able to use the computational resources efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot tell you where the super-linear memory consumption comes from. Do your jars behave differently when you start 14 instead of 10? Do you use IPC or some communication between your program instances?

Answer (score 1):

To use the computational resources efficiently, you would have to start one `jar` which starts multiple threads in one JVM. If you start 14 instances of the same `jar`, you have 14 isolated JVMs running.

Comment: Sure, I saw that solution too. But will it be a concern if each of my threads need a lot of memory and 1 JVM cannot afford the total memory demand? Or in that case I just need to increase the amount of memory (heap/stack or whatever...) assigned to the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

- Get ids of all java processes using [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)
- Get the most heavy weight process using [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)
- Get heap dump of that process using the same [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html).
- Analyze heap usage with [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html)

  - Alternatively you could copy dump locally and explore with tools like [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Open Source Project](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

If after solving this issue you totally loved these shell like tools(as I do) go through complete list of [java troubleshooting tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/#troubleshoot) - it will save you a lot of time so you could go to pub earlier instead of staying late and debugging memory/cpu issues